# Non Uniform Density Rod Center of Mass

Tags: definite-integrals

Consider a rod in three dimensional space where $y$ is the height axis. $h$ is the height of the rod and $a$ is the radius of the rod. The function $\rho(r, \theta, y)$ is the density function. The mass of the rod can be calculated with

$$
m =\int_{y=0}^{h}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{a}\rho(r, \theta, y)rdrd\theta dy
$$

similarly the center of mass in the y direction is

$$
C_y = \frac{\int_{y=0}^{h}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{a}y\rho(r, \theta, y)rdrd\theta dy}{m} \label{1}
$$

How can the center of mass in the $x$ and $z$ direction and or in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ be expressed?

Comment: Definitely an issue. For example if you have a rod thats radially uniform, then the center of mass would be 0 but the integral with respect to r would be positive

Comment: A "rod" is generally a linear instrument.  You say that $a$ is the (uniform?) radius of the rod, so presumably the rod has a circular cross-section but perhaps density varies as a function of $r\in [0,a]$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$.  So while the cross-sections are uniformly circular, their density can vary arbitrarily?  I'm guessing at your meaning, but a (right circular) *cylinder* might be a better term for the figure.

Comment: @hardmath The density can vary with all three variables $r, \theta, y$ within their domain however it wants, continuously, continuously whatever. Otherwise yes, I think you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert these coordinates back to $r$ and $\theta$ using $r=\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$ and $\theta=\displaystyle \arctan\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)$.

$\displaystyle C_x = \frac{\int_{y=0}^{h}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{a}r\cos(\theta)\rho(r, \theta, y)rdrd\theta dy}{m}$

$\displaystyle C_z = \frac{\int_{y=0}^{h}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{a}r\sin(\theta)\rho(r, \theta, y)rdrd\theta dy}{m}$

Comment: damn that's a large angle expression, good thing it works

Comment: Wait I think this solution is a bit problematic. I am numerically solving these triple integrals so the limits need to be constant. The limit for $x$ expressed as $\sqrt{a^2 - z^2} = \sqrt{a^2 - (rsin(\theta))^2}$ varies with $\theta$ right? That does not work for my case. Also are you saying that it would be more accurate if I were to use the larger expression for $\theta$ instead of $arctan(\frac{z}{x})$ as argument for $\rho$?

Comment: yes, about the other expression, because arctan only works for positive x

Comment: oh no, i'm literally dumb. the other method (for x, for example) would be to use polar integration, but instead of multiplying by x, multiply by rcostheta, and divide by mass as usual

Comment: for z, use polar coordinates again, but multiply by rsintheta, and divide by mass

Comment: it's 3 am, and it seems like my brain is working now! can't believe i would've subjected you to that when the answer could've been so simple

Comment: $C_x = \frac{\int_{y=0}^{h}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{a}r\cos(\theta)\rho(r, \theta, y)rdrd\theta dy}{m}$

Comment: @SakethMalyala Thank you a lot for your answer. Could you remove the first bad solution to remove any confusion for other readers?

Comment: @SakethMalyala isn't it supposed to be arctan z / x

Comment: oh yeah my bad ,,

Answer (score 0):

Calculate center of mass along radial direction. Then put $\theta=0$ for x direction and $\theta=\pi/2$ for z direction

Comment: By radial do you mean in the $y$ direction? Also do i use the same expression for $C_y$ when getting the center of mass for $x$ and $z$ only having the limits changed?

Comment: Actually I am not sure about the answer. I was trying to say that, you calculate $C_r$, then  use different values of $\theta$ to find the center of mass the corresponding direction.